# Responsive full-width images and srcset

Tags: html, image, responsive-images, srcset

I have a site where I want some full-width images (they'll be cropped vertically, for a parallax look). I want to I've read a bunch of articles on `srcset` and `sizes` and tried a few things, but I can't figure out (a) whether I need to use "sizes" at all, and (b) especially without `sizes`, how the browser will choose which image to load.

For concreteness, here's an image spec:

```html
<img src="/images/full/2c8n.jpg" srcset="
  /images/320/2c8n.jpg 320w,
  /images/640/2c8n.jpg 640w,
  /images/1024/2c8n.jpg 1024w,
  /images/full/2c8n.jpg">
```

This is in a full-width container div so the image should go edge to edge.

I'd like it to load the smallest one on mobile and the largest one (the `/images/full` one) on big desktops, but that doesn't seem to be happening. I've seen that it's possible to use `x` style as well, but I'm not sure how I'd choose which image to use with each scale factor, if that's even the right way to do it. Any idea what I'm doing wrong and what's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is pretty unclear about the `sizes` attribute. What I've been able to determine is that it only affects what size to render the image, and NOT image selection. So, `sizes="(max-width: 500px) 50vw, 100vw"` tells the browser:

1. if the viewport is up to 500px wide, render the image at 50% of the viewport (50vw)
2. if the viewport is 501px or larger, render the image at 100% of the viewport (100vw)

For the `srcset` attribute, the browser takes a look at your list of images, guesses at what size the slot is it should fill and then chooses the next size up. So, edge to edge as per your requirement, this is how it would choose which file to use:

1. Viewport width up to 319px -> /images/320/2c8n.jpg
2. VW 320px to 639px ->          /images/640/2c8n.jpg
3. VW 640 to 1023 ->             /images/1024/2c8n.jpg
4. VW 1024 and larger ->         /images/full/2c8n.jpg

I've also read, but haven't verified yet, that it uses the first image it finds that fits the requirements between the `src` and `srcset` tags. The order of the attributes may make a difference. Again, read but not verified.